# Debug & Run Angular2 Typescript with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

**Debug & Run Angular2 Typescript with Visual Studio Code?**

I am trying to debug Angular2 typescript application with VS code
https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Can anyone please share steps to debug & run from VS code?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

After lot of research, I found these steps-

Before you begin, make sure you have latest version of VS code. You can verify latest version – Help > Check For Updates or About.

1. Install extension called 'Debugger for Chrome'. Once install complete, restart VS code.
2. Go to Debug window, open launch.json using Chrome.
3. In Launch.json configuration section, use below config

   ```
   {
       "name": "Launch localhost with sourcemaps",
       "type": "chrome",
       "request": "launch",
       "url": "http://localhost:3000/Welcome",
       "sourceMaps": true,
       "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
   }
   ```
4. In tsconfig.json, make sure you have "sourceMap": true

This completes your debug environment settings.
Now, before you start debugging, make sure all your existing Chrome.exe instances are closed. Verify from Task Manager OR Use DOS command ‘killall chrome’

5. Run your project, using npm start command and Chrome as default browser.
6. Once application is run successfully, you will receive port number. Copy URL from chrome browser and paste into url section above.
   (NOTE: If you are using routing in your application then url would like above otherwise it will be ending index.html etc)
7. Now, place breakpoints wherever you want in your typescript files.
8. Again, go to debug window in VS code, and hit Run. 
   Your tab/instance connected to debugger will looks like below.

[image: Chrome Debugging]

Comment: can't understand..
1. which extention  to install.
2. where is Launch.json?

Comment: @azulay7 Are you using VScode for first time? Its VScode not Visual Studio 2015 IDE.  
Anyways, On left side, you will see **Debug** option (or use CTRL+SHFT+D) click to open Debug window. 
Once you open Debug window, on top right side of Debug window you will see option for **open Launch.json**. 
For chrome extension, you will see **Extension** option (or use CTRL+SHFT+X) on left side. 
Once you open Extensions windows, search for **Debugger for Chrome** Install this extension. You will have to restart VScode.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I was also struggling with "open launch.json". The steps are as follows: click on "Debug" icon in the left sidebar, then click on the cogwheel at the top right corner of the Debug window and choose "Chrome" from the drop-down list if it appears.

Comment: Anyone else getting `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (http://localhost:3000/)`

Comment: I'm also getting connection error on the debug port? `HTTP GET failed: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9222` Loading up on localhost fine.

Comment: Fixed that by making sure all the chrome instances were shut down, my issue now seems to be an angular-cli sourcemap complication

Comment: Could you also show your full ` tsconfig.json` as well, please? I haven't made one thus far.

Comment: @PaluMacil here is my tsconfig.json `{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
    }
}` It is same as quickstart article on angular2 site.

Comment: I didn't understand all the steps but I opened a new question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443217/angular-2-debug-with-visual-studio-code-not-working as my problem is mostly with Linux I guess. In case it help anyone to find another question about that ... ;)

Comment: I managed to have a partial improvement (I can now receive console.log in VSC but breakpoints not working. CF previous comment with stackoverflow link for more info)

Comment: When you download the chrome debugger extension you can view the extensions page in vscode and will give you examples and instructions on how to set this up.

Comment: Do we really have to close all chrome instances ? If true, this is the worst debugger I've ever see... Can't we launch a separate window with parameter ?

Comment: I think that now default port for Angular5, created with Angular-CLI, is 4200, so the url should be `http://localhost:4200` you can also see it in the console where you started the app with `ng serve`.

Answer (score 15):

Specify a userDataDir - this will avoid collisions with other Chrome instances you may already have running. I've noticed because of this, Chrome just stops listening on any port you specify. Below is what I use and it is great!

```
{
    "name": "Launch",
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "url": "http://localhost:3000/#/about",
    "port": 9223,
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "diagnosticLogging": true,
    "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "userDataDir": "${workspaceRoot}/out/chrome"
}
```

Thanks to @reecebradley - [GitHub: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/issues/111#issuecomment-225101947)

Comment: Still one may get issues.. I moved my code base to C:\(root) drive, debug was working fine.

Comment: angular 2 chrome debugging not working has weird reasons.. some times checkin all pending into source control, take a clean folder, latest, debug starts working...reason I dont know.. :(

Comment: I am using below launch json - consistently could run the debug mode code\0/: {
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [ 
{
"name": "Launch localhost with sourcemaps",
"type": "chrome",
"request": "launch",
"url": "http://localhost:4200/",
"webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/app/files",
"sourceMaps": true
},
{
"name": "Launch",
"type": "chrome",
"request": "launch",
"url": "http://127.0.0.1:4200",
"port": 9222,
"sourceMaps": true,
// "diagnosticLogging": true,
"trace" : "verbose",
"webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
"userDataDir": "temp"
}
]
}

Comment: TRY launch option for live debugging instead of with source maps!

Answer (score 5):

I was having a similar issue but my project also included webpack that caused the above solutions to fail. After traversing the Internet I found a solution in a thread on github:

https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/144#issuecomment-218721972

Anyway, this is what was done.

**Note:-** Before you start you must check whether you have the latest version of visual studio code and also have installed the extension called '[Debugger for Chrome](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/23/introducing-chrome-debugger-for-vs-code)' within VS Code.

Firstly, in './config/webpack.dev.js'

- use => *devtool: 'source-map'*
- instead of => *devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map'*

Then install and use the write-file-webpack-plugin:

- *npm install --save write-file-webpack-plugin*

Add the plugin to './config/webpack.dev.js' by adding:

- *const WriteFilePlugin = require('write-file-webpack-plugin');*

under the Webpack Plugins at the top. Continue to add:

- *new WriteFilePlugin()*

to the list of plugins after new new DefinePlugin(), i.e

```
plugins:[
    new DefinePlugin({....}),
    new WriteFilePlugin(),
    ....
]
```

***This ensures that the source maps  are written to disk***

Finally, my launch.json is given below.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost, with sourcemaps",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000/",
        "runtimeArgs": [
           "--user-data-dir",
           "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
        ],
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "diagnosticLogging": true,
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "userDataDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/chrome"
    },
    {
        "name": "Attach to Chrome, with sourcemaps",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "attach",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000/",
        "port": 9222,
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "diagnosticLogging": true,
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
    }]
}
```

notice the absence of '/dist/' in the webroot. with this config, source-maps are in ./dist/, but they point to ./src/. vscode prepends the absolute root to the workspace, and correctly resolves the file.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an official visual studio code documentation on how to debug Angular in VSCode https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/angular-tutorial#_configure-the-chrome-debugger

> To debug the client side Angular code, we'll need to install the Debugger for Chrome extension.
>   Open the Extensions view (Ctrl+Shift+X) and type 'chrome` in the search box. You'll see several extensions which reference Chrome.
>   Press the Install button for Debugger for Chrome. The button will change to Installing then, after completing the installation, it will change to Reload. Press Reload to restart VS Code and activate the extension.
>
> We need to initially configure the debugger. To do so, go to the Debug view (Ctrl+Shift+D) and click on gear button to create a launch.json debugger configuration file. Choose Chrome from the Select Environment dropdown. This will create a launch.json file in a new .vscode folder in your project which includes configuration to both launch the website or attach to a running instance.
>   We need to make one change for our example: change the port from 8080 to 4200.

Comment: What if I would like to run Internet Explorer and not Chrome?

Comment: I don't know why you would want to do that, but currently there is not IE support.

Answer (score 3):

I had issues with this and while @Sankets answer helped it was this issue that solved it for me https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2453.

Specifically adding the below to launch.json

```
"sourceMapPathOverrides": {
    "webpack:///c:/foo/bar/angular-project/*": "${workspaceRoot}/*"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For angular-seed:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug with chrome",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:5555",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src/client",
      "userDataDir": "${workspaceRoot}/out/chrome",
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "app/*": "${webRoot}/app/*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These mods to `launch.json` worked for me on MacOS, which enabled me to get the debugger & breakpoints working in a new instance of Chrome per debug session...

```
// This forces chrome to run a brand new instance, allowing existing
// chrome windows to stay open.
"userDataDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/chrome",
"webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
"sourceMaps": true,
"sourceMapPathOverrides": { "webpack:///./*": "${webRoot}/*" }
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is tried and tested -

**Step 1:** Install chrome debugger: simply open the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) inside VS Code and type Extensions: Install Extension command. When the extension list appears, type 'chrome' to filter the list and install the Debugger for Chrome extension. You'll then create a launch-configuration file.

[[More Details of Step 1]](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/23/introducing-chrome-debugger-for-vs-code)

**Step 2:** Create and update launch.json file: Two example launch.json configs with "request": "launch". You must specify either file or url to launch Chrome against a local file or a url. If you use a url, set webRoot to the directory that files are served from. This can be either an absolute path or a path using ${workspaceRoot} (the folder open in Code). webRoot is used to resolve urls (like "http://localhost/app.js") to a file on disk (like "/Users/me/project/app.js"), so be careful that it's set correctly.
update Content of launch.json file as follows-

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch localhost",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost/some_name",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/wwwroot"
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch index.html (disable sourcemaps)",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "file": "${workspaceRoot}/index.html"
        },
    ]
}
```

[[More Details of Step 2]](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug)

Answer (score 0):

I need to use `CORS` so I open chrome in with disabled web security. Then I do debugging of Angular application by attaching debugger to chrome.

CMD line to launch chrome with disabled web security:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\"
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

`launch.json` file for attaching debugger:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
            "port": 9222,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Sanket's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37605661) was correct but I had some problems with that.

First, Launch.json is in the ".vscode" directory of the project, and
second, port number should be the same as the default server port you use for launching your app. I use **ng serve** from cmd for launching my project and the default port number was **4200**, so I changed the launch.json file as follows.

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```