# what are the possible way to debugg typescript with angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

i have created a sample application in angular 2 using typescript. 
what are the possible way to debugg typescript with angular 2 in developer tool.

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: is any possible way to debugg typescript with angular 2 in visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use chrome development tool. Here is the [doc](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/). You may want to start on "Inspect & Debug Javascript" section

Comment: is any possible way to debugg typescript with angular 2 in visual studio?

Comment: how to debugg typescript section?

Comment: Assuming you are using Visual Studio Code, you can follow the steps described on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494938/debug-run-angular2-typescript-with-visual-studio-code)