# Error processing "launch": Error: Can't find Chrome - install it or set the "runtimeExecutable" field in the launch config

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug an Angular 2 application using VS Code. To change the browser in which it launches from IE to Chrome, I installed the debugger for Chrome.

This is what the launch.json contains:

```json
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
]
```

After starting the project (using `ng serve --open`) and on trying to debug, I get:

```
Error processing "launch": Error: Can't find Chrome - install it or set the "runtimeExecutable" field in the launch config.
<p>at Object.errP (C:\Users\rahs\.vscode\extensions\msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome-4.1.0\node_modules\vscode-chrome-debug-core\out\src\utils.js:207:13)
<p>at launch.then (C:\Users\rahs\.vscode\extensions\msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome-4.1.0\out\src\chromeDebugAdapter.js:52:57)
     at anonymous
```

I referred to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443217/debug-with-visual-studio-code-not-working) on the same topic but I'm using Windows and the Windows-specific answer did not work for me.

Comment: Have you tried to set `"runtimeExecutable": "C:/path/to/chrome.exe"` in the `launch.json`?

Comment: That started it! Thanks