# vscode TypeScript debugging in Angular project with F5. Not breaking or in a wrong spot

Tags: angular, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I read many related questions where debugging does not work. In my case it works but it's "weird". I set breakpoint at one line of code but it breaks in completely diferrent line. I feel it's related to source maps, but not sure what it is.

Environment:

- Latest vscode(1.21.1)
- Latest Chrome debugger extension installed
- Lastest npm/angular CLI
- Latest Chrome (65.0.33...)

Generated project using CLI with `ng new`

Following config added for F5 launcher(launch.json):

```
 "configurations": [        
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
```

This is code of `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { isUndefined } from 'util';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "Portal";

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.test();
  }

  test() {
    const person = { FirstName: "John" };
    person.FirstName = "sf";

    let b = "test string";

    b = "other string";
  }
}
```

Set breakpoint on something like `b = "other string"`

Start as usual in terminal `ng serve`
Click F5 - Chrome opens and displays main screen.

**Problem 1:** Chrome doesn't brake at all.

When I refresh Chrome page - Breakpoint get hit but in a wrong place. It can be in `ngOnInit` or on `Component` line, pretty "random".

**Problem 2:** Breaking happens on a wrong line

Is there any way to make this work so I can set and debug without pain using VSCode?

Comment: What OS are you on? I'm on a Mac and get the same behavior. It works the first time but then the breakpoints starts getting off.  Restarting chrome and ng-serve seems to work its not really satisfactory.

Comment: It's on Windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code breakpoint appearing in wrong place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765353/visual-studio-code-breakpoint-appearing-in-wrong-place)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say why things behave oddly with your setup. I also use VSCode to debug Angular apps and my setup works pretty well, I'll share it here so that hopefully it can be of help.

- Make sure you have the [Chrome Debugger extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome) installed
- Modify your `launch.json` to look like this

```js
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "userDataDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/chrome",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--disable-session-crashed-bubble"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Attach Chrome",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "attach",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200",
      "port": 9222,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "sourceMaps": true
    }
  ]
}
```

- Serve your angular app with `ng serve`

You should now be able to start debugging your app (with `F5`) and all the breakpoints should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Can you explain what is the second "attach Chrome" config does? I did make this change - same thing. Brakepoint missed on first run. If I "refresh" - breaks on some invalid/random line comparing to what I set. Latest Chrome debugger extension installed

Comment: Weird... see if this answer can be of any help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443217/debug-with-visual-studio-code-not-working?rq=1

Comment: That answer doesn't help. In my case it's technically "working" because once it breaks I can step through, etc. Looks like problem is with "maps" where breakpoint line # is not correctly checked/applied

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to this question:

[Angular CLI 1.7.0 and Visual Studio Code - can't set breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48892311/angular-cli-1-7-0-and-visual-studio-code-cant-set-breakpoints/49315091#49315091)

The solution there was to install an older version of the angular cli.

Comment: I can set breakpoints, they just not get hit properly and move

Comment: That is the issue in the other question too, even if the title says not able to set, the poster there could set them but they are not hit correctly. Changing to and older Angular cli work for me also.