# How to debug Angular 6 subproject from VS Code

Tags: angular, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I Created a new Angular 6 CLI project

```
ng new myProjects
```

Created 'sub project'

```
ng g mySubProject
```

If I ng serve mySubProject then try to debug from VS Code using my normal launch.json, then breakpoints are not hit.

```
{
  "name": "Launch Chrome (test)",
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "url": "http://localhost:4200/",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
},
```

Can someone guide me how to set up my launch.json to debug sub-projects like this?

(for details on how I have my sub projects set up, it's based on a post
[here](https://medium.com/@SirMaxxx/angular-6-creating-a-shareable-control-library-6a27f0ebe5c2) )

If I just ng serve, then this launch.json debigs the 'main' project OK - so I am guessing I need to set up somewhere in the launch.json to tell it where the child project is?

Comment: I've try to setup all that with VSC and Angular few months ago. You should find everything you need here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443217/debug-with-visual-studio-code-not-working

Comment: Thanks for the comment @maxime1992, but a) I already answered my own question a day before your post, and b) your link doesn't actually answer my question, as my question is specific to debugging sub-projects in Angular 6+

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To debug a sub-project in an Angular 6.0 workspace:
Set your launch.json configuration to look like:

```
{
  "name": "ng serve my sub application",
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "url": "http://localhost:4200",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/projects/mysubapplication"
}
```

This means you will need a configuration entry for every sub application.