# angular2 debugging: breakpoint not getting hit at execution only at initialization

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug my angular2 app with source map by placing a breakpoint in the .ts file.

```
foo(){
   //breakpoint here
   console.log('bar');
 }
```

the breakpoint only gets hit when loading that component and not when executing.
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

put `debugger;` in the line where ever you want.browser will definitely pauses;

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need an answer, but assuming you're doing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37605661/2378943), I believe angular runs some code only once (like constructors / initialization ... etc).

If the break point is only getting hit once, it is probably because angular intends for that. Try putting your breakpoint in a method that you know for sure gets called multiple times. Try to figure out [where your code is](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html#!#components in the bigger picture of the architecture of an angular app.

Otherwise, would need more context/info to properly answer.

Answer (score 0):

Closing and opening the browser, solved my issue.