# Debugging Angular 2(typescript) in Visual Studio Code

Tags: debugging, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

Getting below Error while debugging in VS Code for Chrome:

**Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Cannot connect ...**

Already looked into the below thread: and followed the process:
[Debug & Run Angular2 Typescript with Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494938/debug-run-angular2-typescript-with-visual-studio-code)

My launch.json :

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch localhost with sourcemaps",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000/hi",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If you open up Chrome Dev Tools and hit ctrl + p and search for a file can it find your typescript files?

Comment: Can you see more of that error message if you make the window wider (or open the developer tools on the Code window and check in the console?)