# How to setup VSCODE for Angular2 with Typescript debugging without NPM Script Runner

Tags: angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I couldn't find a sample document that demonstrates how to setup [vscode](/questions/tagged/vscode) for [angular2](/questions/tagged/angular2) via [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) debugging without [npm](/questions/tagged/npm) **Script Runner**.

[Quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/package.json#L6-L21) is a generic solution that would work even IDE is not VSCODE

So simply I'm asking for a documentation/repository about how to convert all commands below into VSCODE tasks without spending hours to figure out correct syntax/structure.

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
```

> In-case you think this is a duplicate of another question such as [Debug & Run Angular2 Typescript with Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494938/debug-run-angular2-typescript-with-visual-studio-code) **please** make sure that provided answer is not using `npm start`.
>
> ***e.g.** accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37605661/439130) of that question uses it at step 5*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debug & Run Angular2 Typescript with Visual Studio Code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494938/debug-run-angular2-typescript-with-visual-studio-code)

Comment: questions are similar indeed but not duplicate.  I'm asking a way to do it without using _LITESERVER_ which is the accepted answer for that question.