# Debugging Typescript code in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have been searching on the internet and most people are saying it should debug by default but on my code it isnt, when I put a breakpoint on the .ts file I get [image: picture of the breakpoints]

Please advise on how I can make these breakpoints work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debug & Run Angular2 Typescript with Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494938/debug-run-angular2-typescript-with-visual-studio-code)